# Django - how to set a default to request.session upon login?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `request.session['url']` to store URL and use it to go back to a previous page in a couple of views in my django app.  It works really well, except in one case... right after login, the `request.session['url']` is empty as it gets only populated when using some views.

so, if I go directly to a view that expect to find something in `request.session['url']`, it crash.

Is there a way or a place to set a `request.session['url'] = 'home'` as soon as the user logs in?

Thanks

Comment: Handle the raised exception. It is BTW a good idea in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this instead:

```
default_url = '/home'
request.session.get('url', default_url)
```

It gives you a default value if there is none in the session.